# Return temperature data in Google Sheets for a specific time of day for each day of the month

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column for date and time formatted like so: [3/4/18 1:09] (verified that this is stored as date/time values), and a column for the temperature data at that time in °C like so: [11.536]

There is a reading for every minute and over a month this adds up to over 40K entries.

What I want to do is to make a separate column for the temperature readings for a specific time of day for each day of the month.

So for example I want it to tell me the temperature for 9:00 AM for every day of March.

I'm then going to compare these readings to the daily and monthly temperature averages.

I would like to stick to using functions and not use pivot tables since I'm going to be doing some other things with this later.

Comment: Is your date/time column stored as date/time data or text?  If it is stored as date/time, the data collection process likely does not produce an exact time to all significant digits, so selecting a specific time would be more complex (testing to within some margin of error of the target time value).  I'd be tempted to use a helper column where you extract the time in an exact form.  Then filter on that to select the values you want.

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell what it's formatted as. It's displayed exactly like my above example [3/4/18 9:00] in both the cell and the function bar when I select the cell. So how can I extract the time in an exact form if I were to use a helper column? Sorry I'm extremely rusty/new with this stuff, and I've had no formal training. By the way, I'm doing this primarily in Google Sheets, which is why I included that tag to begin with.

Comment: One way to tell is to reference a date/time cell in another cell (like =A2).  Format that cell as a number.  If it is stored as a date/time, you will see a number, probably in the 40 thousands), which is how a date/time is stored internally.  If your date/time column is text, use text functions to extract the time portion to the helper column.

Comment: Okay, I just tried that. When I referenced my A2 [3/3/18 23:59] cell and pressed Enter, it turned into a number [43,163.00].

Comment: Google Sheets is off-topic here (on-topic on Webapps).  Sometimes solutions will work the same in both, sometimes not.  Looks like the values are stored as date/time.  Assuming you are referencing a date/time value in A2, you could use =HOUR(A2)&MINUTE(A2), which will return a text version of the 24 hour time (military time) rounded to the nearest minute.  Then filter on the time you want.

Comment: Okay, so I would still use a helper column, use that =HOUR(A2)&MINUTE(A2) function to convert the date/time information to 24 hour format, then use a filter to find the time I want (0900). But how will it know to pull the temperature data that time? P.S. Is there a way to add screenshots here?

Comment: Actually, to force 4 digit times, you would need =TEXT(HOUR(A2),"0#")&TEXT(MINUTE(A2),"0#"), which will force a leading zero for single-digit hours or minutes.  If you use a filter, it will hide all of the non-matching rows, so you just pull the data you need from the columns you need.  An easier way may be to use a pivot table.  Select the columns you want (e.g., date/time, temperature), and filter on the helper column for the time.  I don't use Google Sheets, so I can't help you on how to do that.

Comment: If you need to do this in Google Sheets, we should probably migrate your question to Webapps so you can get a relevant solution.

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort in helping. We can move it to Webapps if you think it's necessary, but so far the functions are the same for both. I'll often be converting back and forth between Excel and GS including for this project. I'm mainly working with GS right now because at the current moment I have an old 2010 version of excel that isn't compatible. Anyway, I want to avoid using pivot tables since I need to translate this stuff to another program later.

Comment: FYI, filtering only hides the non-applicable rows.  If you want clean selected data, filter, copy the relevant columns, then paste in the target location. Only the selected values will be pasted.

Comment: BTW, if you want to further filter, like by month as well as time, just tack on another function to add that to your helper column string.  ex, `=TEXT(MONTH(A2),"0#")&...`

Comment: If I need to use a filter, I don't understand why I need to convert the date/time to plain numbers. Is the filter thing not able to read whenever it says 9:00 or something?

Comment: Right.  Time is stored as a floating point number, the decimal fraction of a day.  Those are rarely exact numbers.  So even if the data capture source was perfectly precise, the stored value isn't.  It's rounded to display in the chosen format.  Because of that, there will usually be some amount of error that prevents an exact match.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. So I got it to filter all the values for 9:00 each day and was able to copy/paste that into a new column with just those days. Excellent! now I at least have that data filtered out. Thank you! However... That seemed like a lot of manual copy/pasting on my part, and I was sort of hoping for a way to somewhat automate the process or write a function that would be automatable if you know what I mean. I'm going to be working with bucket loads of this type of data. This little project was just my testing ground.

Comment: Also after this, I then need a way to get the daily temperature averages so I can compare the single-time data to the daily average, but I can make a separate question for that if necessary.

Comment: Once you have your data, you can use the AVERAGE function to give you the average. I would think your task would lend itself to automation. At least in Excel, you can record the manual steps to a macro. It may need a little customization, but it will be a good starting point.  Give it a try.  If you run into a specific problem, people here or at Webapps can help (but it won't get a good reception if you just post task requirements and ask people to write an application for you).

Answer (score 0):

A:A:DateTime
B:B:Temperature

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGEIFS(B:B,TIMEVALUE(A:A),">8:59",TIMEVALUE(A:A),"<9:01"))
```

Comment: I'm not trying to average the temperatures for 9:00. I want it to spit out the exact reading that it took at 9:00. However I am indeed trying to average the temperatures for each entire day to compare the first value to. I tried using your array formula to do this, but it didn't work, so I'm still trying to work out that part of it. So for all temp readings on 3/4/18 for example, I want to average those. Then I want another average for all temperature values on 3/5/18, and so on.

Comment: There must be multiple readings as there are "9:00" in each day. Which "9:00" reading do you want to spit it out? This will be a lot easier, If you share a sheet with sample input and a desired output. Or even screenshots.

Comment: Right, so with Fixer's function here =TEXT(HOUR(A2),"0#")&TEXT(MINUTE(A2),"0#") I made a helper column of just numbers corresponding to the times. I was then able to use a simple filter to filter out all values except for the ones on lines matching the  090 time in the helper column, and then I copy/pasted the results into a new column for just the 9:00 values for each day in march. However If It's possible to make it recognize and  automatically spit out ONLY the values for 9:00 every day into it's own dedicated column without having to manually use filters that would be even better.

Comment: So to answer your question I want it to tell me what the temperature was at 9:00 for each day of March. I also don't know how to upload a screenshot here.

Comment: Try `=FILTER()`